# RegExpre in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want search a 3 numbers (optional with decimal digit), I try using 
`preg_match()` in PHP, but that no filter using the regex  `/^\d{1,3}([,.]\d)?$/`

input:

```
    8631.0
```

output:

```
    array (size=2)

    0 => string '368.6' (length=5)

    1 => string '.6' (length=2)*
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: Your input and output is not understandable because of lack of information how you working to get that output? what you want to do what you are trying?

Comment: I want to validate a number with 3 digit and one decimal number(optional). the html input  pass to the php script. and the regexp validate that this number is ok or not, if this is ok return the number or else 0.
My problem is: I tried with invalid numbers and the script return the invalid number. I think that my regexp is bad. Can you help me please?  @anantkumarsingh

Comment: Check now, i gave an answer.

Comment: please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression need modification,Please try this:-

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}+(\.[0-9]{1})?$/', "631.0",$matchess));
echo "<pre/>";print_r($matchess);
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/754920

Again :-

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}+(\.[0-9]{1})?$/', "8631.0",$matchess));
echo "<pre/>";print_r($matchess);
```

output:- http://prntscr.com/7549g4

Note:- You used var_dump and i used print_r for showing in a better and understandable manner.

Comment: if you got your solution then mark it as an answer. thanks. it will help others to get solutions easily.